# Blogdown + Hugo doesn't show Rmarkdown plots on netlify

Tags: r-markdown, netlify, hugo, blogdown

I'm creating a Blog using Rmarkdown + Hugo's theme (Anatole). After updating the Blogdown package (1.3.2) and with Hugo version 0.85.0 and having problems seeing plots/pics.

The template is working well from RStudio through GitHub to Netifly. I can see all the plot/pics when I publish (because all the pics in the template are in the ***static/images folder***.

However, when I create a new post (***blogdown:::new_post_addin()***), the whole content (including the pics) are store in a different folder: ***content/English/post/2021-01-XXXXX/index_e_files/figure-html***. Hence I can't see the pics.

*Is there any configuration that I need to modify that allows fetching the pics from the corresponding folders for every single post?*

Attaching GitHub Repo
https://github.com/arehor/BlogTest2

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found a workaround to this issue:

1. I stage, commit and push the whole project
2. In the config.yamal I replaced the baseURL variable with the one provided by Netifly, after rendering and publishing the blog/web page: Domain Settings -> Custom Domain -> Default subdomain
3. Save config.yamal, then stage, commit and push again.